# How to code python function that adds n spaces between characters in a str?

Tags: python

There shouldn't be a space before the first char or after the last one.

I need a function

```
def spaces2str(n,s)
```

Where, if n=3, s='foobar'
it should return 'f   o   o   b   a   r':

```
>spaces2str(3,'foobar')
'f   o   o   b   a   r'
```

Comment: you didn't leave a test case and what you expected the test results to be

Comment: added a test case, and fixed the n

Comment: Dupe: [Python adding space between characters in string. Most efficient way](//stackoverflow.com/q/18221436) (plus [In Python, how do I create a string of n characters in one line of code?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1424005))

Answer (score 6):

If I have understood well you want to put `n` spaces between the characters. In that case this one liner would do the job:

`(' '*n).join(s)`

Comment: No need to call `list(s)`. Just use `s`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey You're right. Thanks.